# Why does paraview give an error even when the number of cells in the lattice and the number of data points match?

Tags: paraview

Why does paraview throw up the error "Number of cells do not match" when instructed to open a .vtk file? I have carefully checked the file for an inadvertent mismatch between the number of points and the number of cell_data points. There is no such mistake in the file. I know there is no way one can find the source of the error without looking at the code. However, it seems files cannot be uploaded here. As a workaround, I post here a short code written in the same format as the original code. This code also suffers from the same problem.

```
    # vtk DataFile Version 2.0
    avpol
    ASCII
    DATASET STRUCTURED_GRID 
    DIMENSIONS   2    2    2
    POINTS   8 float
    1.00000000000000000000      1.00000000000000000000      1.000000000000000     
    1.00000000000000000000      1.00000000000000000000      2.000000000000000 
    1.00000000000000000000      2.00000000000000000000      1.000000000000000     
    1.00000000000000000000      2.00000000000000000000      2.000000000000000
    2.00000000000000000000      1.00000000000000000000      1.000000000000000     
    2.00000000000000000000      1.00000000000000000000      2.000000000000000 
    2.00000000000000000000      2.00000000000000000000      1.000000000000000     
    2.00000000000000000000      2.00000000000000000000      2.000000000000000         

    CELL_DATA   8
    SCALARS avpol float 1
    LOOKUP_TABLE default
    6.1878484E-02
    9.0861745E-02
    0.1041844    
    0.1083797    
    0.1151097    
    0.1139994    
    0.1119415    
    0.1097126     `
```

Comment: can you share the file instead of the text of the file ?

Comment: Hi Mathieu, if my knowledge of stackoverflow is correct, files cannot be uploaded here. I googled "uploading file onto stackoverflow", which took me to a few questions regarding the same and they all have the same answer " files cannot be uploaded there". Could you please let me know how I should go about sharing the file?

Comment: I figured out the source of the error. The problem was with the vtk file format. I misread its documentation and set the number of lattice points equal to the number of data points. This is simply wrong because the data points correspond to the centres of these cells. Thanks to one of my colleagues, the mistake was spotted quickly.

Comment: Feel free to answer to yourself then. You could have uploaded the file via wetransfer for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for being willing to help me out.